# Is it possible to dereference a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c

I have a two-D array of pointers to structs. I am trying to copy the structures to spots pointed to by other array elements. The clear way, to me, to do it is just assign each value using the dereference operator. I do not want to do `array[0][1] = array[1][0];` because that would assign the address of the struct. So I was wondering if I could do

```
*array[0][1] = *array[1][0];
```

as a quicker way to copy structures?

Comment: use `memcpy` to copy the size of the struct

Comment: `I have a two-D array of pointers to structs. I am try...` please show us the definitions, as source code.

Comment: What does "copy the value of the pointers to other spots in the array" mean, exactly? What does or doesn't work about the solution you've tried already, shown in the question? Can you show a more complete piece of code?

Comment: The “value of a pointer” is the address. If you are “trying to copy the value of the pointers,” you are copying the pointers. Then saying “I don't want to do `array[0][1] = array[1][0];` because that would assign the address of the struct.” is inconsistent, because you just told us you want to copy (assign) the addresses. If you want to copy the structures, not the addresses, then you should have written “I am trying to copy the structures the pointers point to.” So your question is unclear. Also, `*(array[0][1])` does not dereference the array; it dereferences an element.

Comment: My apologizes, this is meant to represent a chess board. I understand that the value of a pointer is the address. Each pointer is pointing to a struct that represents a piece. Thus, copying the address into another index of the array would make it seem like the piece is there twice. I should have been more specific, and said I wanted to copy the contents of the pointer into the new index of the array. @EricPostpischil

Comment: You are still doing it. One phrase in your comment says you do not want to copy the address because “copying the address… would make it seem like the piece is there twice.” Another phrase says you do want to copy the address because it says “I wanted to copy the contents of the pointer.” Stop writing “contents of the pointer.” If you mean the structure, say “the structure” or “the contents of the structure” or “the object pointed to by the pointer.”

Comment: Similarly, you cannot copy “the contents of the pointer” into “the new index of the array.” In `array[0][1]`, the indices of the arrays are 0 and 1, and you cannot copy the contents of the pointer into 0 or into 1. The things that are in the array are elements, not indices. You either want to copy pointers to array elements or copy structures (pointed to by array elements) to structures (pointed to by array elements).

Comment: I am sorry. I want to copy the structures pointed to by array elements. I do not want to copy the address. Sorry for my misuse of terms. Thank you for rectifying my mistakes. @EricPostpischil

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant: Why do you recommend `memcpy`? Simple assignment works for structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a *struct*, a simple assignment is fine.  `memcpy()` is not necessary - nor is that function call preferred.

```
struct {
  int piece;
  int color;
} chessman;

chessman p1, p2;
...
p1 = p2;
```

With an array of pointers to a `struct`, it is OK too.

```
chessman *array[8][8] = { 0 };

array[1][0] = malloc(sizeof *(array[1][0]));
assign_data(array[1][0]);

array[0][1] = malloc(sizeof *(array[0][1]));
assign_data(array[0][1]);
...
chessman empty = { 0 };
*array[0][1] = *array[1][0];
*array[1][0] = empty;
```

Recall that such a copy is a shallow copy.  The below assignment copies the pointer in member `other_data`, not the contents of what `other_data` references.

```
struct {
  int piece;
  int color;
  foo *other_data;
} chessman2;

chessman q1, q2;

q1 = q1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

You could do the `*(array[0][1]) = *(array[1][0]);` to copy a struct-object, yet you'll have to ensure that `array[0][1]` already points to some memory allocated properly. So if `array[0][1]` has not been initialized so far, you'd write

```
array[0][1] = malloc(sizeof(*array[0][1]));
*(array[0][1]) = *(array[1][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array elements (pointers) reference the properly allocated place there is no more efficient way of assigning structures.

Compiler knows the size of the structure and will emit the most efficient code for it. `memcpy` way will way slower.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    double b;
    char c;
}a;

typedef struct 
{
    int a[5];
    double b[10];
    char c[100];
}b;

typedef struct 
{
    int a[50];
    double b[100];
    char c[100];
}l;


volatile a c[5];
volatile a *d[5] = {&c[0], &c[1], &c[2], &c[3], &c[4]};

volatile b e[5];
volatile b *f[5] = {&e[0], &e[1], &e[2], &e[3], &e[4]};

volatile l m[5];
volatile l *n[5] = {&m[0], &m[1], &m[2], &m[3], &m[4]};


void foo(void)
{
    *d[2] = *d[4];
}

void foo1(void)
{
    *f[2] = *f[4];
}

void foo2(void)
{
    *n[2] = *n[4];   
}
```

---

and the resulting code:

```
foo:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR d[rip+32]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR d[rip+16]
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx+16]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+16], rdx
        ret
foo1:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR f[rip+32]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR f[rip+16]
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+16]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+16], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+32], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+48]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+48], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+64]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+64], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+80]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+80], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+96]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+96], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+112]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+112], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+128]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+128], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+144]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+144], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+160]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+160], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+176]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+176], xmm0
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+192]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+192], xmm0
        ret
foo2:
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR n[rip+32]
        mov     ecx, 138
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR n[rip+16]
        rep movsq
        ret
```